# email forwarding, apache, cpanel, php

Tags: apache, cpanel, email-forwarding

How does email forwarding works in cpanel (apache server)? I could not find any documentation for this on my client's cpanel itself (i dont have their hosting account only cpanel). Basically, they just want to monitor incoming and outgoing emails in one account. They have 8 email individual accounts and one person wants to monitor each accounts email (in and out) is there a way to do this using cpanel in an apache server.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it's impossible to forward outgoing mail in CPanel. See this link:
http://forums.cpanel.net/f43/possible-forward-outgoing-mail-78332.html
and
http://www.linuxweblog.com/blogs/sandip/20090423/monitor-outgoing-emails-cpanel-exim

Unfortunately I don't have access to exim settings so I'd like to know if there's another solution as well.